# Why would \includegraphics work for a .png but not .eps?

Tags: graphics, eps, png

The following displays the .png figure in the pdf but not the .eps figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=5.0in]{mcs.eps}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=5.0in]{Broncos.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Space is reserved in the pdf for the .eps figure even though it is not displayed. I am using MikTeX 2.9 and TeXMaker 5.0.4.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Because `.png` is natively supported by the PDF format, whereas `.eps` is not, so it requires additional packages to convert it to a supported format (PDF). Also, off-topic: you can select the code and click the `{}` button to format as a code block in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Phelype.  Here are the packages I am using in my full code:  \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{epstopdf}  What am I missing?

Comment: @Craig Sorry, I forgot to mention in my comment that the conversion of `.eps` to `.png` is done automatically by `graphicx` you don't need any other packages to do that. Your code works fine for me...

Comment: you say you are using pdflatex but then say you are using psfrag, which requires latex not pdflatex?

Comment: you also should not need epstopdf package (graphicx calls that automatically if needed)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, all.  I have tried both PDFLatex and Latex, but when I use the latter I receive this warning, "Drivers other than `pdftex' and `luatex' are not supported" and it does not compile.

Comment: normally pdflatex can handle eps-files (it automatically convert it to pdf). If it doesn't work for yours there is perhaps a problem with the eps itself and you should it make available somewhere. Also you should show the log-file of your document.